# Pull out part of the page URL

Tags: javascript, url, path, location, substring

My page's URL is like this:

`http://www.mydomain.com/directory/thisismy_page.html`

Using JavaScript, I want to pull out the part of the page's filename before the underscore. So in this example, I want:

`thisismy`

I currently have this:

`var filename = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);`

But that pulls out `thisismy_page.html`. How do I "stop" it at the underscore so all I get is `thisismy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filename=filename.split("_")[0];
```

This splits it at the underscore and takes the first (or 0th part).